# axios api calls pointing towards my localhost in nextjs application it is workign fine on serverside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

i am using axios library in my nextjs and react application  i am able to call the api from the server using getStaticProps() it renders the intial data properly but when i am making call from client(browser) side to append more data to my list it is hitting wrong URL it is pointing to my server (localhost) instead of the API server

I have made axios interceptor in my server for base URL config and additional headers

when I am making request via axios from serverside the API end point is https://example-api/vi/userlist but when I am making it from the client side via same interceptor config the API endpoint is like localhost:3000/userlist

below is my azios instance

```
let instance = axios.create({
     baseURL: https://smaple-api/v1,
     headers: {
     "Appapi-Id":"h4er9jdt33i6_8r37mg"
     }
  })
```

My api.js file from where I have done reference of the api

```
const feedsApi = { 
     userFeeds : (apiUrl,data) => {
     return http.post(apiUrl,data)
}

export default feedsApi;
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and include your code?

Comment: Are both running on localhost? Then you may have problems with cross-origin

Comment: @MunsMan no for api they are running on the dev server and my next application is running on my computer machine

Comment: @Cully hi actuallly the interceptor is working fine but only when I am making axios request from the client side it is giving problem the API endpoint should be www.example.com/poductlist but its pointing towards localhost:3000/productlist

Comment: There's no way to know what's wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: Where does the `baseURL` value come from? Is it hard-coded? If it's not hard-coded, then it must come from some configuration, an environment variable for example, which does not exist on the client, but only on the server

Comment: Please update your question and include the code that defines your `baseURL`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are not exporting the interceptor from your interceptor config file, you might just be exporting the axios object from the library itself. Check if that's the case